# Data submission from wtforms not going to database, can't validate submission Flask Sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

Ok, so I can have the data display from the form onto a redirect, but when it comes to submitting it to the database I created, where is the problem?  My log in section works fine, however my sign up section is not submitting correctly.  Here is my code:

```
@app.route('/sign_up.html', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signup():
    form = SignupForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        new_user = usersTable(fname=form.firstname.data, lname=form.lastname.data, email=form.email.data, username=form.username.data, password=form.password.data, joined=date, package=form.package.data)
        new_business = businessTable(businessname=form.businessname.data, businessaddress=form.businessaddress.data, businesswebsite=form.businesswebsite.data, fiscalyearstart=form.fiscalyearstart.data, fiscalyearend=form.fiscalyearend.data, businesslogo=form.businesslogo.data)
        db.session.add(new_user, new_business)
        db.session.commit()

        return '<h1>User has been created</h1>'

    return render_template('sign_up.html', form=form)
```

Also, just so you can see my imports, here is the top layer of my file:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, BooleanField, DateField, FileField, SelectField
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired, Email, Length
from forms import *
from flowdb import *

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY']='GETABETTERKEY'
Bootstrap(app)
```

Comment: Hi, where are you initializing the db instance? I can't see any db import on your code. For example `db = SQLAlchemy(app)`

Comment: That is exactly how i have it instantiated, as well as the uri

Comment: It is right below Bootstrap(app)